# Concatenating 1 to asterisk gives 1 31

Tags: bash

When I run the following code

```
for i in {0..9}
do
    OCTET="*$i"
    echo "i="$i", OCTET=" $OCTET
done
```

I get the following output

```
i=0, OCTET= *0
i=1, OCTET= 1 31
i=2, OCTET= *2
i=3, OCTET= *3
i=4, OCTET= *4
i=5, OCTET= *5
i=6, OCTET= *6
i=7, OCTET= *7
i=8, OCTET= *8
i=9, OCTET= *9
```

I am hoping to get

```
i=1, OCTET= *1
```

as the second line of the output.

Comment: My bash (msys) gives: `i=1, OCTET= *1` with your code.

Comment: @tinlyx that's because you don't have any files matching the pattern `*1` in your working directory.

Comment: @TomFenech right. I was only testing the said behavior on an empty home behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable expansions should be within double quotes:

```
for i in {0..9}
do
    OCTET="*$i"
    echo "i=$i, OCTET= $OCTET"
done
```

Outside of double quotes, the `*1` is glob-expanding to the name of two files in your current working directory, `1` and `31`. It would appear that none of the other patterns (`*0`, `*2`, `*3`, etc.) match any files, so they are displayed literally.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `$OCTET` (without quotes) you are asking the shell to attempt to match the value of the variable as a filename pattern. So if the files `1` and `31` exist, then `*1` will be substituted with that list of names.

If you didn't intend for that to happen (and you probably didn't), you should *quote the expansion*: `"$OCTET"`.